# Can we have a "joint comment" option to summarize/replace long-winded disagreements?

Tags: feature-request

It happens to everyone.  You overstate your own knowledge and get a sharper than usual critique... your response is unnecessarily critical of critic... and **because you both have points to make you talk past each other and it snowballs.**  At best the comments spend an embarrassingly long time to come to a simple conclusion.  Now, often it is best to delete the comments.  But this forgoes an opportunity:

1. There is a chance to reconcile with mutual trust and respect.
2. Both sides can rephrase their points to be brief and professional.
3. The topic/point could be something subtle that is a common source of disagreement (one that others can better understand and learn to avoid).

Can we implement a "replacement comment" or "summary comment" option?

EXPLICIT DEFINITION:  A proposed "joint comment" from one person to replace comments from multiple people (pending approval of all involved).

Comment: Comments aren't for discussions. If the mis-understanding is resolved, and the knowledge preserved in the post, just purge the comments (flag a mod to do it).

Comment: As a social matter, you can apply whatever convention you want... As long as it's understood by the other party. Alexei's suggestion is ideal for this: edit the conclusion that reflects your understanding into the post itself, and leave one last reply to the effect of, "Finally I understand; please let me know if my edit addresses your concern appropriately."

Comment: @Deduplicator  Flagging a mod is an involved process.  More importantly, please read this carefully: Discussions that are boiled down to the useful information are no longer discussions.  They are information... that is exactly what I am proposing there be a process for.

Comment: @Shog9 What you described as current setup is PRECISELY what I discussed in my first paragraph.  I stated I found the status quo lacking because it ends up presenting (at best) a long answer to an obvious question... an argument instead of a single point.  Deleting comments forgoes the opportunity to salvage a point of contention that others might find useful *because it often comes up as an argument*.

Comment: @PaulRoub Stackexchange and Meta policy (and based on answers to questions about the topic of down votes) is very, very clear that questions should be downvoted based on the quality of the question.  Upvotes for a response that says "no" is how to to disagree without saying it was an inappropriate question to ask.  I did NOT expect people to agree with me... what I DID expect was to be heard without negative feedback for asking a question that has not been asked.

Comment: Please consider the possibility that, when you find yourself "hav(ing) to remind" people how things work, there's at least a *chance* that you might be mistaken. *"On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."* [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @PaulRoub i just found that page actually... I missed it the first time I researched Meta differences (I honestly did look into this before posting updates and responses... will edit the question as necessary). Thanks for your patience... I thought I was losing rep etc. so I was somewhat perturbed...

Answer (score 15):

No.

Better approach (existing) is to edit question/answer with result of discussion and delete all related comments.

Comment: I think this is a fair but the downvotes tell me people feel this was an inappropriate question to ask and that leaves me somewhat mystified.  Is it a repeat of a previous question?

Comment: My direct response would be that someone can normally only delete their own comments... this would allow a summary that replaces comments from many parties.

Comment: Voting is different on meta - more often than not it's used to signal agreement/disagreement with a feature request. Doesn't mean it's a bad question, doesn't mean it doesn't belong here, nothing like that. Don't take it personally, I doubt the voters are

Comment: @Clive Thank you for the input Clive!  I actually did check out Meta-specific guidelines and answers to questions regarding downvotes before responding.  As far as I could tell it seemed to work the same but it does help to hear someone on here sees it that way.  My main follow-up question is this:  What about concrete consequences, like losing rep?  People may not be meaning it to be personal but it is still affecting me in a very negative way.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). One of the ways in which it is different: votes on Meta do not affect your rep.

Comment: Thanks all for handling this well... I thought my rep was taking a nosedive which I hope everyone understands was a little distressing.